# Identifying "." and absence of whitespace in a string through "if ... if"

Tags: javascript, if-statement, indexof

I want to identify whether, in a string, there is no whitespace after "."

I tried a nested if statement, but it doesn't work. I guess I am missing something really simple.

Also, I read Regex might do this, but I couldn't wrap my head around the syntax.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var invocationInitial = document.getElementById('spokenNames');
    if(invocationInitial) {
    var invocation = invocationInitial.innerHTML.trim();
    }
    var counter = 1;
    var message = '';

    if(invocation.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
    if(/\s/.test(invocationInitial) === false)
    { 
    message = counter + ". No dot in string without subsequent whitespace";
    counter = counter +1;
    }
    }

    if(message) {
       alert(message);
    }
})();
```

A browser warning ("message") should be displayed if "invocationInitial" does *not* have every every occuring dot (".") followed by a whitespace.

var counter is introduced here, because in the full version, multiple browser warnings will be shown based on different conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RegEx you need here is pretty simple: `/\.\S/` . That says "match a dot not followed by a whitespace character". Note that `\s` means "match a whitespace character" while `\S` (capital S) means "match anything that is NOT a whitespace character".

So you can simply do this:

```
if (/\.\S/.test(invocation)) {
    // There's a dot followed by non-whitespace!
}
else {
    // There is no dot followed by non-whitespace.
}
```

Comment: Done @Brock Adams, sorry for the delay. Need to learn the ropes.